# Use vim to delete everything in a paragraph

Tags: vim

I want to use vim to delete everything inside of a paragraph tag. Is there a way? (d i p) does not work like di " does or di>. I have tried everything but I do no see anything online for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To borrow an answer from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim), you can use `vit`

- `v` = visual select
- `i` = inside
- `t` = tag

And see also `:help v_it`

And of course you can change the action from `v` to `d` to delete instead of select, or my favorite, `c` to replace it (deletes it and enters insert mode so you can type something else).